# Faraday::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I enable in gitlab ce 10.1.4 (omnibus) Container registry.

Add external nginx conf.

Get https://git.XXX.com/web/repo/container_registry 500 error

In console: docker login git.XXX.com:5005 and output:

> Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (error
>   during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.27/info:
>   open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file
>   specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker
>   client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate
>   that the docker daemon is not running.). Using system default:
>   https://index.docker.io/v1/

In nginx/error.log:

> WARNING: Unexpected middleware set after the adapter. This won’t be supported from Faraday 1.0

In production.log:

> Started GET “/web/repo/container_registry” for ip at 2017-11-21 20:35:50 +0300 Processing by
>   Projects::Registry::RepositoriesController#index as HTML Parameters:
>   {“namespace_id”=>“web”, “project_id”=>“repo”} Completed 500 Internal
>   Server Error in 33ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
>
> Faraday::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read
>   server hello A: unknown protocol):
>   lib/container_registry/client.rb:19:in repository_tags'
>   app/models/container_repository.rb:36:inmanifest’
>   app/models/container_repository.rb:41:in tags'
>   app/models/container_repository.rb:53:inhas_tags?‘
>   app/controllers/projects/registry/repositories_controller.rb:48:in
>   block (2 levels) in ensure_root_container_repository!'
>   app/controllers/projects/registry/repositories_controller.rb:47:intap’
>   app/controllers/projects/registry/repositories_controller.rb:47:in
>   block in ensure_root_container_repository!'
>   app/controllers/projects/registry/repositories_controller.rb:44:intap’
>   app/controllers/projects/registry/repositories_controller.rb:44:in
>   ensure_root_container_repository!'
>   lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:47:inwith_locale’ lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:53:in
>   with_user_locale'
>   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:337:inset_locale’
>   lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:93:in call'
>   lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:14:incall’
>   lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:17:in call'
>   lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:11:incall’

External nginx.conf:

> upstream gitlab-registry { server localhost:5000 fail_timeout=0; }
>
> server { listen 5005 ssl http2; server_name git.XXX.com;
>   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/git.XXX.com/fullchain.pem;
>   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/git.XXX.com/privkey.pem;
>
> server_tokens off;
>
> client_max_body_size 0; chunked_transfer_encoding on;
>
> ssl_ciphers
>   'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-
>   ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1; ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
>   ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m; ssl_session_timeout 5m;
>
> access_log /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_registry_access.log; error_log
>   /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_registry_error.log;
>
> location / { proxy_set_header Host $http_host; # required for docker
>   client’s sake proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; # pass on real
>   client’s IP proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For
>   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto
>   $scheme; proxy_read_timeout 900;
>
> proxy_pass          http://gitlab-registry; }
>
> }

ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]

gem list:

...
faraday (0.13.1, 0.12.2)
faraday_middleware (0.12.2, 0.11.0.1)
faraday_middleware-multi_json (0.0.6)
...

Help me please!

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: @MichaelYagudaev the problem itself has disappeared.

Comment: I've upgraded version and that seem to solve it